# arraylist java.util.ConcurrentModificationException initialize from other class

Tags: java, arraylist

I get the following exception stack trace:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.ConcurrentModificationException
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.checkForComodification(ArrayList.java:901)
    at java.util.ArrayList$Itr.next(ArrayList.java:851)     at
    Controllers.Manager.createTheNetwork(Manager.java:123)  at
    Controllers.Main.main(Main.java:53)
```

Why do I get this stack trace? I've just initialized an `ArrayList` from another class.

## Main.java

```
public class Main {

    private static Manager  anager;
    private static ArrayList<Vfoo> aVfooList;
    private static ArrayList<Pfoo> aPfooList;
    private static ArrayList<Nfoo> aNfooList;
    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        
        aPfooList = new ArrayList<Pfoo>();
        aVfooList = new ArrayList<Vfoo>();
        aNfooList = new ArrayList<Nfoo>();
        
        aPfooList.add(new Pfoo());
        aPfooList.add(new Pfoo());
        
        for (Pfoo p : aPfooList)
            if (!p.isAMethod())
                aVfooList.add(new Cfoo());
        
        aNfooList.add(new Nfoo());
        aNfooList.add(new Nfoo());
        
        manager = new Manager();
        manager.setList(aList1);
        manager.setList(aList2);
        
        manager.createSomething();
}
}
```

## Manager.java

```
import java.util.ArrayList;

public class Manager {

    private ArrayList<Nfoo> nfooList = new ArrayList<Nfoo>();   
    private ArrayList<Vfoo> vfooList = new ArrayList<Vfoo>();   
    
    
    public NodeManager (){
        
    }
    
    
    public ArrayList<Nfoo> getNfooList(){
        return nfooList;
    }
    

    public void addNfooToTheNfooNetwork(Nfoo n){
        this.nfooList.add(n);
        System.out.println(n);
    }
    
    public void addANewVfooToTheNetwork(Vfoo aVfoo){
        getNfooList().get(0).addToStack(aVfoo);
    }
    
    
    public void addANewTfooToTheNetwork(Tfoo t, int whichNfoo){
        getNfooList().get(whichNfoo).addToStack(t);
    }
    
    public void resetNfooNetwork(){
        nfooList.clear();
    }
    
    public void createSomething(){
        for (Nfoo n : nfooList)
            addNfooToTheNfooNetwork(n);
    
        for (Vfoo v : vfooList)
            addANewVfooToTheNetwork(v); 
    }
    
    
    public void createSomething(ArrayList<Nfoo> nl, ArrayList<Vfoo> vl){
        
        this.setNfooList(nl);
        this.setVfooList(vl);
        
        for (Nfoo n : nfooList)
            addNfooToTheNfooNetwork(n);
    
        for (Vfoo v : vfooList)
            addANewVfooToTheNetwork(v); 
    }
    
    public void setNfooList(ArrayList<Nfoo> nl){
        this.nfooList = nl;
    }
    
    public void setVfooList(ArrayList<Vfoo> vl){
        this.vfooList = vl;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: did you read the javadoc for ConcurrentModificationException?  or any of the myriad of similar questions on SO already?

Comment: every answer said about using the iterators. Im not using iterators here or add or removing items using them. I have just tried to set the arraylists from the one class to another..

Comment: the code is like:

setVfooList(newList)

and the newList has ConcurentModificationException when I am trying to use it..

Comment: If I'm not mistaken `for each` loops, like `for (Pfoo p : aPfooList)`, use iterators.

Comment: really? I didn't know that the behind implementation uses iterators.

Comment: `for (Nfoo n : nfooList)
            addNfooToTheNfooNetwork(n);` this seems to be adding each element in nfooList back into nfooList while iterating which is the problem

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Indeed, as it is written in the comments you are using Iterators. Check the documentation for the for looping :  `for (Obj o : objectList)`

As @Nagesh Susaria said in the comments, your actual mistake is that you are trying to re-initialize or just add new `Nfoo Objects` into your ArrayList while the `Iterator` from the loop is parsing it. 
Check the following:

```
 for (Nfoo n : nfooList)
   addNfooToTheNfooNetwork(n);
```

and

```
public void addNfooToTheNfooNetwork(Nfoo n){
    this.nfooList.add(n);
    System.out.println(n);
}
```

As you will see, the "glitch" of your code is in the `this.nfooList.add(n);` or  `addNfooToTheNfooNetwork(n);` . 
Both of them are doing the same I guess. Delete one of them and you are ok!